# Redirect all requests for www. to root domain

Tags: python, django, heroku, redirect, dns

I need to redirect all requests coming from `www.mysite.com` to `mysite.com`

I have found the [solution in rails](http://blog.dynamic50.com/2011/02/22/redirect-all-requests-for-www-to-root-domain-with-heroku/), but how can I do that in Django/Python?

The only solution I could find, which was posted by a moderator on GoDaddy was the above. Seems like I cannot resolve this kind of problem through the DNS Manager of GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

class WWWRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META['HTTP_HOST'].startswith('www.'):
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('http://example.com')
```

Comment: And how would you use that if you're also running a local dev server?

Comment: @alper use an if not DEBUG for example

Answer (score 10):

Create your own middleware in `[PROJECT_NAME]/middleware.py`, like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class RemoveWWWMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Based on the REMOVE_WWW setting, this middleware removes "www." from the
    start of any URLs.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        if settings.REMOVE_WWW and host and host.startswith('www.'):
            redirect_url = '%s://%s%s' % (
                request.scheme, host[4:], request.get_full_path()
            )
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Then, in your project's `settings.py`:

- Add `REMOVE_WWW = True`
- And add `[PROJECT_NAME].middleware.RemoveWWWMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list, after Django's SecurityMiddleware and preferably before Django's Common Middleware.
- Also, of course, make sure you haven't set `PREPEND_WWW = True`

This middleware is based on [Django's CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/middleware/common/#CommonMiddleware).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - I can confirm that this solution works perfectly with Django==2.0.2. Thanks a lot, Jeff! I was having trouble doing this from the DNS side.