# How do I redirect www request to non-www domain

Tags: django, heroku, redirect, dns, dnsimple

I have a Django site on Heroku with Dnsimple to manage DNS. I am also using Django to force HTTPS.

I am trying to follow google protocol so that I only have one domain

`https://example.com`

So that if a user visits `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com`
it will redirect to `https://example.com`

My settings in Dnsimple look like this:

```
ALIAS   example.com     example.com.herokudns.com
CNAME   www.example.com  example.com.herokudns.com
```

I tried deleting the cname and using the URL redirect in Dnsimple, but it isn't working.

What is the correct way to do this redirect?  I've tried creating a middleware based on another outdated post, but it crashed my site.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi yes you need to create custom middleware in Django as Dnsimple does not handle redirect of https addresses.  Follow this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759030/heroku-django-redirect-all-requests-for-www-to-root-domain/46233639#46233639